# My Informatiion design tool is getting closed without prior notice?

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects, universe

I'm a beginer in IDT (SAP BO client tool Information design tool).After establishing a connection and starting a session, it closes automatically when i add some tables(1 or 2  tables added and it will be closed.. i mean the entire IDT))

Comment: Sounds like a bug.  I would update to the latest version if possible, or open an incident with SAP.

Comment: did you look the windows event log ?